# $(x^2+1)\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove that ideal $M:=(x^2+1)\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a maximal ideal in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Which field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/M$?

Please, help me to solve this problem. I have an exam tomorrow and I have no idea what's going on in this task. Please, help!

Comment: Hint: this is a field extension of $\mathbb R$ of degree 2.

Comment: You should use "field" instead of "body" (as you know).

Comment: Ok. In Polish is body :)

Comment: exactly in Polish "field" - "body" - "ciało" :)

Comment: Probably Polish took the term from the French *corps*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the application$$\phi:\mathbb{R}\left[X\right]\ni P\longmapsto P\left(i\right)\in\mathbb{C}.$$
 I let you check that this is a surjective homomorphism.

Now we want to determine its kernel. We have $\phi\left(X^{2}+1\right)=i^{2}+1=0$
 whence $$\left(X^{2}+1\right)\mathbb{R}\left[X\right]\subset\ker\phi.$$
The difficult part is to show the converse. If $Q\in\ker\phi$, let us consider the euclidian division of $Q$
  by $X^{2}+1$
  : we write$$Q=\left(X^{2}+1\right)R+S$$
 with $Q,S\in\mathbb{R}\left[X\right]$
  and with $\deg S\leq\deg\left(X^{2}+1\right)-1=1$. Hence, $S=aX+b$
  with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, since $Q\in\ker\phi$ and since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we have$$0=\phi\left(Q\right)=\phi\left(\left(X^{2}+1\right)R+S\right)=\phi\left(X^{2}+1\right)\phi\left(R\right)+\phi\left(S\right)=\phi\left(S\right)=ai+b$$
 and thus $a=b=0$, i.e. $S=0$ and $Q\in\left(X^{2}+1\right)\mathbb{R}\left[X\right].$

By the factorization theorem, we get$$\mathbb{R}\left[X\right]/\left(X^{2}+1\right)\mathbb{R}\left[X\right]\simeq\mathbb{C}.$$
 The fact that the ideal $\left(X^{2}+1\right)\mathbb{R}\left[X\right]$
  is maximal comes form the fact that $\mathbb{C}$
  is a field.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong \mathbb{C}$ is a field, the ideal ${\frak{m}}=(x^2+1)$ is maximal.

Comment: What theorem apply?

Comment: This theorem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147047/shorter-proof-of-r-i-is-a-field-if-and-only-if-i-is-maximal).

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: It proves only it's a prime ideal.

Comment: But in a PID, all nonzero prime ideals are maximal.

Comment: @Bernard In a PID [every prime ideal $\ne 0$ is maximal.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/865305/242) Being Euclidean, $\,F[x]\,$ is a PID. But I agree it should be explicitly mentioned in any proof.

Comment: I think it has to be mentioned.

Comment: What is a PID? I don't know.

Comment: Principal ideal domain; every ideal is of the form $aR$ for some $a \in R$.