# A commutative ring with identity is a field if and only it has no nonzero proper ideals

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Obviously, if $F$ is a field, and $I$ is it's nonzero ideal, then it contains an invertible element of $F$(any nonzero element of $F$). Denote this element as $a$. Since $I$ is ideal, $aa^{-1} = 1 \in I$. Hence, $I = F$.

But I'm not sure how to prove that any commutative ring with identity without nonzero proper ideals is a field.

Comment: Please try the search feature first, next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think backwards:

If you have a commutative ring $R$ with identity, the only missing property to be a field is, that any element is invertible.

So let's assume $R$ is no field. You have some non-invertible element $r \neq 0$ and thus $rR$ is a proper ideal, since $1 \notin rR$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{0\}$  is the only proper ideal, is a maximal ideal and $R/\{0\}\approx R$ [is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147047/shorter-proof-of-r-i-is-a-field-if-and-only-if-i-is-maximal).

Comment: Well, OK, but I I would tend to think of *"commutative rings with no nontrivial ideals are fields"* as the essential reason why *"the quotient of a commutative ring by a maximum ideal is a field"*, not the other way around...