# Correspondence theorem in Ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, intuition, ring-isomorphism

What does the correspondence theorem (or 4th isomorphism theorem for rings) for rings mean and how is it used? That is, why do we care about it?

---

Edit:

My version of the correspondence theorem:

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Let $K$ be the set of ideals in $R$ containing $I$. Let $L$ be the set of ideals in $R/I$. Then there is bijection from $K$ to $L$ given by $\phi(I’)= \{ x+ I : x \in I’ \}$.

Comment: Could you include a quote of _your_ version of the theorem (phrasings differ from source to source)? That would make it easier for us to explain what it means.

Comment: I’ve edited my post including a statement of my version of the correspondence theorem.

Comment: $K$ being a set of ideals makes this the third isomorphism theorem. The fourth concerns subrings. At least in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most basic applications of this theorem is the result that a quotient ring $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal. (For me, all rings are commutative with unity.)

Every non-zero ring $R$ has at least two ideals, namely $\{0\}$ and $R$. And $R$ is a field if and only if these are the only two ideals in $R$.

If $I\subseteq R$ is a proper ideal, then there are at least two ideals in $R$ containing $I$, namely $I$ and $R$. And $I$ is maximal if and only if these are the only two ideals in $R$ containing $I$.

Now the set of ideals in $R$ containing $I$ is in bijection with the set of ideals of $R/I$. So $I$ is maximal if and only if there are exactly two ideals in $R$ containing $I$ if and only if there are exactly two ideals in $R/I$ if and only if $R/I$ is a field.

Comment: Nice! I never thought of proving it this way!

Answer (score 0):

The correspondence says that if $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$, that the following map is a bijection:

$$\{\mathrm{\ ideals \ of \ R \ containing \ I}\}\to \{\mathrm{ideals \ of \ the \ quotient \ ring \ R/I}\}$$
$$J \mapsto J/I = \pi(J)$$

where $\pi: R \to R/I$ is the natural quotient map.

We have a similar correspondence for subrings of the quotient ring.

---

Why do we care about it? Because it tells us that we know how ideals in the quotient ring look like and complete knowledge of ideals of $R$ gives us complete knowledge about the ideals in the quotient ring.